# template function pointer overloading

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, function-pointers

I have a template function like

```
template<typename T> T ABS(const T& DiIN){
    return (0 > DiIN) ? T(DiIN * (-1)) : T((DiIN));
}

template<typename T> T ADD(const T DiIN1, const T DiIN2) {
    return DiIN1 + DiIN2;
}
```

I need to call the function ABS and/or ADD using a single function pointer. 
Currently I use two different function pointer names, but found it is getting complicated when I include more template function with different argument length.

my current implementation is like

```
template<typename T>
struct test {
    std::string funcName;
    T(funcptr1 *)(T);
    T(funcptr2 *)(T, T);
};

test<int> ltest[] = { {"ABS", ABS, NULL}, {"ADD", NULL, ADD} };
```

Is there a way to 
1) Use a single function pointer
2) get rid of the initialization `test<int>` and use `test<T>` so that I can use any variable type during runtime?

I am looking for a simple initialization like

```
template<> //template<typename T>
test<T> ltest[] = = { {"ABS", ABS}, {"ADD", ADD}, ..... };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use a single function pointer?

There is probably a way of doing that using `std::function`. However, you can get the simplicity you are looking for by providing a few constructors.

```
template <typename T>
struct test {

   using function1_type = T(*)(T);
   using function2_type = T(*)(T, T);

   test(std::string fname, function1_type f1) : funcName(fname), funcptr1(f1), funcptr2(nullptr) {}
   test(std::string fname, function2_type f2) : funcName(fname), funcptr1(nullptr), funcptr2(f2) {}
   test(std::string fname, function1_type f1, function2_type f2) : funcName(fname), funcptr1(f1), funcptr2(f2) {}

    std::string funcName;
    function1_type funcptr1;
    function2_type funcptr2;
};
```

Now, you will be able to use:

```
test<int> ltest[] = { {"ABS", ABS}, {"ADD", ADD}, {"MIXED", ABS, ADD} };
```

If you want to disallow use of `{"MIXED", ABS, ADD}` to construct an object, you can remove the last constructor.

BTW, in order to use the above, you'll need to modify `ABS` and `ADD` so that the argument types don't have `const` or `const&`. They need to be:

```
template<typename T> T ABS(T DiIN){
    return (0 > DiIN) ? T(DiIN * (-1)) : T((DiIN));
}

template<typename T> T ADD(T DiIN1, T DiIN2) {
    return DiIN1 + DiIN2;
}
```

> Is there a way to  get rid of the initialization `test<int>` and `use test<T>` so that I can use any variable type during runtime?

No, you cannot do that. The types used to instantiate a template *must* be known at compile time.

Comment: @R Sahu: should I still need to use funcptr1 to call ABS and funcptr2 to call ADD?? Is there a way to implement the same using variadic template?

Comment: @user2896993, you can probably do it but it won't be straight forward. I am curious. Is there a real problem you are trying solve, or this an intellectual curiosity?

Comment: @R Sahu: I need a solution for this. There are about 700+ such small template functions with different datatypes and argument length. My code is getting lengthier and time consuming during runtime, if I use if else or switch case to identify which function pointer(function) I need to call.